# static method in react native bug(callback)

Tags: react-native

I will try my best to explain the problem i have.

here is a sample code

auth.js

```
static authenticate(email,password,callbackIsLogged)
 {
     //some logic
     if(passwordCorrect)
     {
         callbackIsLogged(true);
     }
     else
     {
         callbackIsLogged(false);
     }
 }
```

login.js

```
loginButtonClicked()
{
    Authcontroller.authenticate(email,password,function(loginState)
    {  
        if(loginState)
        {
           alert('correect');
           //proceed withlogin.
        }
        else
        {
           alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

the problem i have is weired. 
lets look at a sample scenario where this bug happens.

if i login with correct username and password for the first time when the app opens everything goes according to plan.
But if i enter the incorrect password at the first time and the second time enter the correct password the callback function will get called twice with boolean value true and false.

It seems like the static function somehow hold the previous callbacks and execute them.

hope you undestood my question. how to fix this.

thanks.